# I am encountering internal server error 500

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I m trying to use a html page with a servlet using jdbc, the page displayed fine but when i clicked on the add botton it shows the error below:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Description:  `The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.`

I am using `tomcat 9.0.4` and `mysql server`.

Here is my code:

```
 package com.teejay.userservlet;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;

 import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



 /**
   * Servlet implementation class CreateUserServlet
   */
 @WebServlet("/addServlet")
 public class CreateUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Connection con;

/**
 * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
 */
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    try {
        con =            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "Olamilekan1$%");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
IOException {

    String firstname=request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastname=request.getParameter("lastName");
    String email=request.getParameter("email");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");

    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        int result = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into user values('"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+email+"','"+password+"'); ");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if (result>0) 
        {
        out.println(result + "value(s) inserted");
        }

        else {

            out.println("Error inserting values... ");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 /**
 * @see Servlet#destroy()
 */
   public void destroy() {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


     }






here the html ...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add User</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Registration:</h1>
<form method="post" action="addServlet">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input name="firstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name :</td>
            <td><input name="lastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td />
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And

I expected the values to taken from the html page to the database.

Comment: It further shows...

Comment: Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.teejay.userservlet.CreateUserServlet.doPost(CreateUserServlet.java:52)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: please check if you have got a connection properly from the database. It seems it has not got the connection successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below line get the connection in `init` method.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

It should resolve your problem

Comment: please share your  `web.xml` ? How you made connection to jdbc database ?

Comment: I am not using xml. I use  @WebServlet("/addServlet") annotations

Comment: @Ramon So I have created very simple `servlet` program which takes user input from the ui and persist data in database(mysql). Please find the github link to download the project https://github.com/rosmahajan/java-servlet. I have created very similar project and it is able to persist data in database.